# Can cofibrant replacements of k-linear categories in dg-cat be found k-linear?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Hello everybody, this is my first question in MathOverflow. I hope it will be of interest.

Let me fix permanently a commutative ring $k$. Every dg-category will be considered to be over $k$.

Let $\mathcal A$ a (small) dg-category. It is known that the category $\mathbf{dg\text{-}cat}$ of small dg-categories has a model category structure; hence, we are able to find a *cofibrant replacement* of $\mathcal A$, namely, a cofibrant dg-category $\mathcal A_{cof}$ together with a quasi-equivalence $\mathcal A_{cof} \rightarrow \mathcal A$. In particular, $\mathcal A_{cof}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal A$ in the homotopy category $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathbf{dg\text{-}cat})$.

My question is the following: suppose our $\mathcal A$ has complexes of morphisms concentrated in degree 0, that is, $\mathcal A$ is indeed just a $k$-linear category. Then, can I find a cofibrant replacement of $\mathcal A$ in $\mathbf{dg\text{-}cat}$ which is too $k$-linear?

My "stupid" attempt was to consider the category $H^0(\mathcal A_{cof})$ (where $\mathcal A_{cof}$ is an arbitrary cofibrant replacement of $\mathcal A$, as above), but it doesn't seem to work well.

Thank you in advance for any answer!

Comment: No. The problem is not with the `number' of objects, but with the underlyng graded category, which should be a retract of a `polynomial' dg-category. As a counterexample, you can take $A=k[x]/x^2$, or a commutative polynomial $k$-algebra on more than one variable.